# CakePHP 3 - How to install Theme Plugin including assets with Composer?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I am in the process of creating a theme plugin for CakePHP 3, which will enable all of us to quickly bake admin panel with a high quality user interface.

Besides cakephp plugin files, there have many assets files that should installed in /plugins/Admin/webroot/ css, js, img folder.

It would be nice, if possible assets files installed from the 'required' repository.

I have so far only used the composer to install plug-ins, I did not pay attention to where and how it works.

This is the default plugin composer files, which will 'Admin plugin' installed in the right place.

```
{
    "name": "Salines/Admin",
    "description": "Admin plugin for CakePHP",
    "type": "cakephp-plugin",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.0.x-dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Admin\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Admin\\Test\\": "tests",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"
        }
    }
}
```

What should be added to this file that I eg twitter bootstrap instead of the vendor folder. installed in Webroot?

Comment: Have you read this article? It looks like asset loading is built in to the `cakephp-plugin` installer. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-assets

Comment: Yes, I have read and I'm looking for a way to install in these folders the required files from other repository.  Looking for a way to make my plugin contains only extended cakephp bake shell files, but that when you install this plugin, also simultaneously install the necessary css and js files.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why don't you simply put bootstrap, etc. in the plugins/Admin/webroot directory with the reset of your assets? It might help if you posted the directory structure of your plugin.

Comment: Yes, think about it. Thank You.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this currently. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/524) about this kind of things, but it doesn't look like a feature to be added soon (or anytime). The best you can try, as suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/524#issuecomment-43568359) is to write a post-install-script to move the files after downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

Read this link

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Then you can create your own repository with Satis. Then you can store your plugins there and your plugins can be installed via composer.

The easy way is that keep your plugins somewhere, then if you need, just copy them to your plugins directory :)